# Show that $2^n - (-1)^n = 3m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Show that $2^n - (-1)^n$  is divisible by 3 for all positive integers n

I tried:

let $n = 2k$ (Even numbers)

$n = 2k + 1$ (odd numbers)

but also, I didn't find the solution.

Comment: This is almost immediate, by induction.

Comment: take mod 3 for both cases

Comment: @amrsa   then what I do?

Comment: @Tim   ha????? I don't understand you.

Comment: @amrsa Yup, I try lots of ways. but I didn't reach any result.

Comment: @Ahmad Alnajjar when we say $11\equiv 8\equiv 2 \:\text{(mod 3)}$, that means 11,8 has the same remainder 2 when divide by 3. So if $a\equiv 0 \:\text{(mod 3)}$, a is divisible by 3.

Comment: Using arithmetic modulo $3$ you get $2^n-(-1)^n\equiv 2^n-2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Modular_arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic),

For $n = 2k$,
$$2^n - (-1)^n=4^k-1$$

Since $4^k \equiv 1 \quad\text{(mod 3)}$,
$$2^n - (-1)^n\equiv 1-1\equiv 0 \quad\text{(mod 3)}$$

So $2^n - (-1)^n$ is divisible by 3 for $n = 2k$.

Leave another case for you.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

In general, we have $$a^n - b^n = (a - b) (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + a^{n-3}b^2 + \dots + b^{n-1}).$$ Hence, $$2^n - (-1)^n=3\times \text{something}.$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

Use $(x^n-a^n) =(x-a) f(x, a)$, then $(2^n-(-1)^n) =(2--1)N=3N.$

Comment: Nice Bézout's theorem implementation.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

The case is clear for $n=1$.

Suppose $2^n - (-1)^n$ is a multiple of $3$, say $3m$.
Then
\begin{align}
2^{n+1} - (-1)^{n+1} 
&= 2\cdot 2^n + (-1)^n \\
&= 2(2^n - (-1)^n) + 2(-1)^n +(-1)^n\\
&= 2(3m) + 3(-1)^n.
\end{align}
I suppose you can reach a conclusion now.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

$$2^n-(-1)^n=3m$$

Let $n=2k$

$2^n-(-1)^n=2^{2k}-(-1)^{2k}=2^{2k}-1=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$

Since an integer is one of these forms $3t-1, 3t$ or $3t+1$ and a positive integer power of $2$ is not a multiple of $3$ then it must be one of the forms $3k-1$ or $3k+1$ and $(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$ is a multiple of $3$

Let $n=2k+1$

$2^n-(-1)^n=2^{2k+1}-(-1)^{2k+1}=2^{2k+1}+1=$

$=(2+1)(2^{2k} - a^{2k-1}  + \ldots + 1)=$

$=3\times (2^{2k} - a^{2k-1}  + \ldots - 2 + 1)$

In both cases $2^n-(-1)^n$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), esp. after they have already been closed, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242),